# MySQL OperationalError when deleting from DataJoint table after restricting with its part table: "You can't specify target table : 'part_table'"

Tags: mysql, sql, datajoint

Using DataJoint Python (0.12.9) on Ubuntu with MySQL 5.7 .

Am running into an error with what I believed to be a fairly standard operation.

Have a table named `Table` with a part `Table.Part`.

Restricting `Table` as such:

```py
Table & Table.Part
```

gives me the entries in `Table` common to `Table.Part`. However, wrapping this in a delete statement (either `delete` or `delete_quick`) as such:

```py
(Table & Table.Part).delete()
```

gives me the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1093, "You can't specify target table '#table__part' for update in FROM clause")
```

Do not understand why "target table" is `'#table__part'` here, when I am attempting to delete from `'#table'`.

Comment: Can we start by sorting out which database you are ACTUALLY using pelase

Comment: updated the post (MySQL 5.7)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work

> (Table & (Table & Table.Part).fetch('KEY')).delete()

"target table" is "#table__part" is likely because you are also deleting entries from the Table.Part table as well (cascade delete)